# Tauri - disable menubar

Tags: user-interface, menu, tauri

So I am trying to disable this menu bar in Tauri

[image]

But I couldn't find where to disable it in the configuration. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your tauri builder (inside main.rs) has a .menu parameter as system default. Either remove it, or replace this menu with your custom one.

You have to change

```rs
tauri::Builder::default()
    .menu(tauri::Menu::os_default(&context.package_info().name))
    .run(context)
    .expect("error while running tauri application");
```

To either

```rs
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .run(context)
    .expect("error while running tauri application");
```

or build a custom menu, and replace it with that one.
Menu docs:
https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/menu/